# Perl - Create date range looking at 3 fields

Tags: perl, date-range

I have 3 Columns of data:

```
Item    |   CreateDate  | Version | 
ABC  |     1/1/2010  |  X      |
ABC  |     3/15/2010 |  XB     |
BBB  |     2/15/2010 |  X      |
BBB  |     6/15/2010 |  X      |
```

How might I populate two additional columns of data named Version Start & Version End that would calculate the start date of the version and the end date of the version for a given Item...based on the CreateDates.

```
Item    |   CreateDate  | Version   |   Version Start   |   Version End
ABC  |     1/1/2010  |  X        |     1/1/2010      |    3/14/2010
ABC  |     3/15/2010 |  XB       |     3/15/2010     |    (04/29/2010)Today
BBB  |     2/15/2010 |  X        |     2/15/2010     |    (04/29/2010)Today  
BBB  |     6/15/2010 |  X        |     2/15/2010     |    (04/29/2010)Today
```

Comment: If you have any control over the format, I suggest switching to an ISO 8601 format to reduce ambiguity.  Almost 40% (144/365) of all dates are ambiguous between US and UK (d/m/y) formats.  Also ISO 8601 is alphanumerically sortable, which is nice.

Answer (score 0):

You can use Date::Calc's Add_Delta_Days function to determine the Version End date, assuming it is a certain number of days after the Version Start date.